# How to read a cson file into R

Tags: r, string, parsing, cson

I came across a cson (CoffeeScript-Object-Notation) file format and I would like to import it into R.

```
cson_example <- "# Comments!!!

# An Array with no commas!
greatDocumentaries: [
'earthlings.com'
'forksoverknives.com'
'cowspiracy.com'
]

# An Object without braces!
importantFacts:
# Multi-Line Strings! Without Quote Escaping!
emissions: '''
Livestock and their byproducts account for at least 32,000 million tons of carbon dioxide (CO2) per year, or 51% of all worldwide greenhouse gas emissions.
Goodland, R Anhang, J. “Livestock and Climate Change: What if the key actors in climate change were pigs, chickens and cows?”
WorldWatch, November/December 2009. Worldwatch Institute, Washington, DC, USA. Pp. 10–19.
http://www.worldwatch.org/node/6294
'''

milk: '''
1,000 gallons of water are required to produce 1 gallon of milk.
“Water trivia facts.” United States Environmental Protection Agency.
http://water.epa.gov/learn/kids/drinkingwater/water_trivia_facts.cfm#_edn11
'''

more: 'http://cowspiracy.com/facts'"
```

Is there a robust way to import cson files into R?

Comment: What is your expected R object?

Comment: Why not use `cson2json` to convert to JSON, then one of the JSON packages in R to read it?